# Not able to Reject or cancel workflow when item is edited

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have created two-level-approval-workflow(SharePoint Designer 2010) on a list.

I want the workflow to stop/cancel/reject when someone edit the original item if the approval process is running.

The workflow is ending/stop properly when the task is pending for the Approval stage 1 and someone edit the original item.

But when the task is pending for approval stage 2 and someone edit the item, the workflow is not getting canceled.
**(I think my workflow is not firing on item change event at this stage.)**

I have attached the screenshot of my workflow.

please suggest me if anyone have any idea.

Thanks

[image]

**Below is the Screen Shot of "When The Item Is Changed"**

[image]

Comment: This looks correct. Can you go into the `ApprovalStage2` process and give us a screenshot of the "When the Item is Changed" step?

Comment: @ErinL Thanks for the response. I have added the screenshot for "When the Item is Changed" of "Approval Stage 2" in my question.

Comment: It all looks right to me. Sorry I can't help.